# How to set inner HTML of a span element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following gives me the error *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier*:

```
$('span.xtro').html('');
$('span.xtro').html('<input type='button' class='newbutton send' value='Send request' onclick= 
                      "javascript:request('send','1','2');'>');
```

**How can I correct this?**

Comment: Have a look at the syntax highlighting, and you should be able to see the problem...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not the best way of using jQuery... onclick attributes are not recommended. here's an alternative

```
//note wrapping with double quotes and using single ones inside 
var $el = $( "<input type='button' class='newbutton send' value='Send request'>" );
$el.on( 'click', function(){ request('send','1','2'); } ); 
$('span.xtro').html('').append( $el );
```

**EDIT** changed $el.bind to $el.on which is what is used nowadays

Comment: This is the cleaner solution. The quotes within quotes within quotes, to the point where you have to escape them, can get pretty complicated after awhile. +1

Answer (score 11):

You're not escaping the single quotes:

```
$('span.xtro').html('<input type="button" class="newbutton send" value="Send request"'
                  + ' onclick="request(\'send\',\'1\',\'2\');">');
```

You can also get rid of the first `$('span.xtro').html('');`, you shouldn't need it.

Comment: +1 Although I'd recommend he/she create the element and attach it instead.

Comment: +1 But, why not open and close with double quotes and leave the original single quotes alone?

Comment: It's up to him which way around he does it, but I just thought I'd highlight the problem :)

Comment: Thank's @Rob W, never noticed that + was missing!

Comment: @BenGriffiths And also the quote of the `onclick` attribute (it was started with a `"`, but closed with a `\'`. Also, `javascript:` is not needed in a `onclick` handler.

Comment: Hanks alot bro @BenGriffiths you are the best

Comment: Haha, I forget half the basics after using jQuery for so long

Comment: @Rob W: $20 says that since his question is answered he will never see this page again.

Comment: @jmort253 - My response was to the comment asking the OP to accept an answer.